# ui-bootstrap datepicker with input type="date"

Tags: angularjs, html, date, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use ui-bootstrap with `<input type="date">`. I get both the popups. I want to suppress the HTML popup.

```
   <input type="date" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
```

Here's a plunker :http://plnkr.co/edit/aCxjDJwhqrzwc1CVrq90?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for chrome only

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
-webkit-appearance: none;
display: none;}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
visibility: hidden !important;}
```

For mozilla and other browsers write a focus event to prevent default.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you want to use input type date?
If you just set the type to text you don't have to suppress anything.

Comment: I want the validation

Comment: As far as i know there is no quick way of changing this behavior. You could do a date validation on the change of the model and check if it is a valid date. But there is already validation on the datepicker of bootstrap.  By setting a format (or multiple formats) you can verify if the input is valid. See the demo's on the [Angular bootstrap site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)